# TypeError: expected str instance, int found

Tags: python

The program creates a password in a string chain tab of a size t. But i can't use the " ".join because there are some "int" that are between the string but i can't understand why.
LETTRES_MIN, CHIFFRES and SYMBOLES are string chains

```
def gen_mp(t, m, c, s):

assert t >= 4, 'might be superior than 4' 
tab = [0]*t
taille = t-1

for i in range(taille):
    if m == True:
        x = randint(0, len(LETTRES_MIN))
        y = randint(0, taille)
        if tab[y] == 0:
            tab[y] = str(LETTRES_MIN[x])
 
    if c == True:
        x = randint(0, len(CHIFFRES))
        y = randint(0, taille)
        if tab[y] == 0:
            tab[y] = str(CHIFFRES[x])

    if s == True:
        x = randint(0, len(SYMBOLES))
        y = randint(0, taille)
        if tab[y] == 0:
            tab[y] = str(SYMBOLES[x])
   
password= "".join(tab)
print(password)
return password
```

the terminal gives me this message back for the test gen_mp(24, True, True, True):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp.py", line 320, in <module>
    gen_mp(24, True, True, True)
  File "mp.py", line 167, in gen_mp
    motdepasse = "".join(tab)
TypeError: sequence item 10: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: You initialized `tab` with ints (`0`) and your code won't necessarily replace all of them, since it replaces a random one each time.  Maybe you want to initialize it with `tab = ["0"]*t` instead?

Comment: i have already seen this, but in my exercice i can't use for..in

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with `''.join(str(t) for t in tab)`?

Comment: i tried to initialize tab = ["0"]*t but it returns me a chain full of 0 :(

Comment: ok ty for your answers, i found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

1 or more entry in `tab` is an int. `join` expecting to have strings only list as an argument.

Possible solution:

```
tab = ['0']*t
```

Or (before you join)
If you will go with this option you no longer need to convert the data you add to `tab` to `str` (`tab[y] = str(CHIFFRES[x])` --> `tab[y] = CHIFFRES[x]`)

```
tab = [str(x) for x in tab]
```